# Calling a function takes forever and then times out with error

Tags: truffle, ganache, eth-call, pure

I wrote this example smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestContract {
    function foo() public pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory strOut;

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            strOut = string(abi.encodePacked(strOut, "This is a lot of text I am concatenating here. This is a lot of text I am concatenating here...\n"));
        }

        return strOut;
    }
}
```

I call the function "foo()" using truffle exec with this snippet:

```
try {
    await instance.foo().then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error -> " + e);
}
```

When I run it the script is waiting forever to get a return value and then aborts with this error:

```
ProviderError:
Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" or "--http" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

Everything works fine if I lower the number of iterations in the loop to for example 10.

Is there a limit on how much computing a pure-function can do or something?

I'm a beginner in smart contract development and set up my environment like described in the Truffle tutorial (Truffle with Ganache).

Comment: Hi AlexXelaAlexXela! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! If I'm not wrong by default it is the block gas limit.

Comment: Thanks! But calling a pure function does not cost gas or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: When executing off-chain it doesn't cost, but to avoid resource exhaustion there's a configurable limit. I think the problem with your code is that it uses too much memory, a new string is created in every iteration.

Comment: Ok, that might be the case. I will investigate that further. But to be clear, will such a function be processed on all nodes of the blockchain or just by one node? And how would such code be handled on the mainnet, does it run out of gas there aswell?

Comment: Edit: I tested this code with remix on Rinkeby and it works without any problems. But still don't know how to make it run on Ganache/Truffle :/

Comment: If executed in a transaction it will cost ether and it will be executed by miners, outside a transaction it is executed by the web3 provider (usually in the caller computer). In Truffle the gas limit can be configured per network in the config file. Also you could use the optional parameter `instance.foo({gas: "10000000"})`. If you have more questions it is better to search in the site, most common question were asked.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. I think it's not a problem with the gas but it's the local vm that can't handle heavy string operations. The remix javascript vm takes forever aswell.